# Rate limiting - using CouchDB with Redis or CouchDB on its own

Tags: couchdb, redis, rate-limiting

I've written an application with a CouchDB backend. I have invested a lot of time into CouchDB and so I'm reluctant to move everything over to a different NoSQL database (like Redis).

The problem is that I now need to implement a rate limiting (based on IP address) feature.

There are [plenty of examples](http://chris6f.com/rate-limiting-with-redis) on how good Redis is for this kind of task, however because I don't want to drop CouchDB for other tasks this means I would essentially be running (and supporting) two databases (1 for most data, 1 for rate limiting) and so...

1. Is running CouchDB in tandem with Redis unheard of?
2. Is CouchDB itself suitable for handling rate limiting itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Is running CouchDB in tandem with Redis unheard of?**

Redis is commonly used in complement with other storage solutions (MySQL, PostgreSQL, MongoDB, CouchDB, etc ...). Like many other NoSQL solutions, Redis is not adapted to *all* kind of workloads or situations. The authors of Redis are pragmatic and open people, and they routinely suggest to use other solutions rather than Redis, when they are more adapted to the situation.

Redis is therefore a good team player, and it is generally easy to integrate in an existing infrastructure.

Here is [an example of usage of Redis with CouchDB](http://blog.mudynamics.com/2012/01/17/blitz-io-using-redis-transactions-with-couchdb/).

**Is CouchDB itself suitable for handling rate limiting itself?**

CouchDB has a number of useful features to implement the rate limiting strategy described in Chris O'Hara's article. For instance, it supports [bulk operations](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API) on several documents (with optional atomicity). A "bucket span" can be stored in a single document. In-place incrementation of counters can be covered by using [update handlers](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers).

IMO, the main missing feature would be automatic item expiration (which CouchDB does not provide AFAIK). So you would have to design a clever mechanism to get rid of obsolete data on top of CouchDB.

The main problem is CouchDB is not really designed for this kind of workload: it is a log structured document oriented database. Each time a counter has to be incremented, it would involve JSON unpacking/packing operations, some Javascript code to be executed, and writing a new revision of the whole document in append only files. You can find a good article describing how CouchDB stores its data [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/107397941677313236670/posts/CyvwRcvh4vv).

I suspect a rate limiting strategy implemented on top of CouchDB would not scale very well (too many I/Os, too much CPU consumption, inefficient network protocol). For instance, CouchDB is a RESTful server; I would not feel comfortable to initiate client HTTP operations (REST queries to CouchDB) to rate limit each incoming HTTP query of my system.

Redis is much more adapted to this kind of workload (fast, in-memory, no I/O, efficient client protocol, no JSON parsing/formatting, incrementations are native atomic operations, etc ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do rate limiting with Memcached - it has a nice counter increment command as you mention, plus obsolete data is automatically purged from the cache in due course, so it has all the benefits of Redis for this application without the annoying duplication of capability (and complexity) that running Redis on top of CouchDB would bring.

http://simonwillison.net/2009/jan/7/ratelimitcache/

You could add memcached to your own setup easily enough or you could investigate CouchBase whose current server product integrates a CouchDB derived database with Memcached compatibility baked in:

http://www.couchbase.com/memcached

Personally I dislike the way Couchbase forked from CouchDB, but for your application it might be a perfect fit.